# Receiving in one line a different number of return values under different conditions

Tags: python

Suppose I have a function that returns a different number of outputs under different conditions; for example

```
def _fn(cond):
    ....
    if cond is 'A':
        return x, y
    else:
        return y
```

And a way to get the outputs of `_fn` is as follows:

```
if cond is 'A':
    x_out, y_out = _fn(cond)
else:
    y_out = _fn(cond)
```

**My question is can I reduce the right above four lines into a single line?**

Comment: My question is why is it important to have it in one line?

Comment: Depends on the output. Maybe you could do `main_result, *rest = fn(cond)`, but it might be a better idea to give the function a consistent number of results (and make the irrelevant ones `None` or similar)

Comment: @roganjosh It is not really necessary. But in my case, it makes my code messy, because I repeatedly need to do it.

Comment: the easiest way would be to return always the same amount of values but with `None` values when you do not need to return the corresponding value

Comment: That sounds like you are doing something really messy if you are doing it all over the place. Note, function can only really return a single value.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ternary notation which was added in version 2.5 of python. You can read more on those [here](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html)

First the `condition` is evaluated and then the if or else result is returned. So you could rewrite your function like this.

```
def fun(cond, x, y):
    return (x, y) if cond == 'A' else y
```

However like already mentioned in the comment I would advise against return multiple different types of results from a single function. Either always return a `tuple` or return a single value.

Comment: I think OP wanted to reduce the _other_ four lines, when invoking the function.

Answer (score -1):

I'd say the best way is to return a tuple including a `None`

```
def wrap_fn(cond):
   res = _fn(cond)
   if cond == 'A':  # or test isinstance(res, tuple)
       return res
   return None, res
```

used as

```
x_out, y_out = wrap_fn(cond)

# then do your code
if x_out is None:
   ...
else:
   ...
```

You can do this in a single line

```
x_out, y_out = (None, _fn(cond)) if cond == 'A' else _fn(cond)
```

but it is messy.

I agree with the comments though, if this is something that is happening a lot, then there is probably a problem with your logic. Functions should return consistent types (especially not returning inconsistent types depending on the *value* of the inputs).